# Can't connect to targetPort of NodePort service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am having a rough time understanding networking on the local machine for my cluster. I have built a simple cluster just to run an Nginx web server for static files using minikube.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: Nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: Nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: Nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: pattersonbl2/webapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: Nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: Nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3088
    name: https
  type: NodePort
```

This will show up on my localhost IP on port 52723. I thought it would be on 3088.  How do you understand what port your content will be served on ?.

Answer (score 1):

> This will show up on my localhost IP on port 52723. I thought it would
> be on 3088. How do you understand what port your content will be
> served on ?.

You have not set the `nodePort` in your file, this means any random node port would be set between  30000-32767. You can set it to some value at the time of creation to be certain of the node port. See description below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: Nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: Nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80              #<---This is internal port for the service which would be forwarded to targetPort
    targetPort: 3088      #<----Application is listning on this, although this seems off, typically nginx listen on 80
    nodePort: <some-port> #<----External traffic would come here, If not set random port would be set between   30000-32767. 
    name: https
  type: NodePort
```